# Forma eficiente de mover tuplas de una tabla a otra, desechando repeticiones de un atributo en concreto

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo dos tablas, y tengo que mover datos de una a la otra. La primera tabla almacena, entre otras cosas, datos de clientes. La segunda tabla está vacía, es donde quiero insertar las tuplas.

La primera tabla tiene esta forma, no la escribo completa en oracle, solo quiero dar una visión de lo que tiene.

```
TABLE CLIENTES{
ID_CLIENTE (primary key)
NOMBRE
APELLIDO1
APELLIDO2
EMAIL(unique)
.
.
.
}
```

La segunda tabla tiene entre otras cosas, todos los atributos de clientes, y son los que tengo que insertar a clientes. El problema está en que no me vale con hacer un:

```
INSERTAR EN clientes
SELECCIONAR  clientid,name,apellido1, apellido2, email, (...)
FROM (tabla_2);
```

El código anterior obviamente no es sintácticamente correcto, es una muestra de cómo hago la consulta. Con lo anterior obtengo un `unique(USER.PK_CLIENTES) constraint violated` porque en la tabla 2 hay ids repetidas.

**¿Qué llevo hasta ahora?**

Tengo localizados cuántos clientes repetidos hay en la tabla 2 usando el `COUNT('X')>1` pero no acabo de acertar con la sintaxis de cómo coger tuplas,   pongamos la del cliente 1, y si se encuentra otra tupla con el cliente 1 no lo meta en clientes. He probado con groups by, min, pero no acabo de acertar porque no lo pongo en el orden adecuado o algo...

EJEMPLO DE CONTENIDO EN TABLA 2:

```
idcliente nombre apell1 apell2 email ... ... peliculas_vistas puntuación

10002     Pedro  Pérez  Pérez  perez@ .. ... avatar           10
10002     Pedro  Pérez  Pérez  perez@ .. ... el rey leon      9
10003     Edu    Rey    Ramos  ramos@ .. ... el rey león      8.5
```

RESULTADO DESEADO EN TABLA CLIENTES:

```
id_cliente nombre apellido1 apellido2 email

10002      Pedro  Pérez     Pérez     perez@
10003      Edu    Rey       Ramos     ramos@
```

No puedo poner tablas intermedias, tengo que trabajar con estas dos únicamente. Básicamente es coger los parámetros que necesita clientes de la tabla 2, pero SIN coger aquellas tuplas cuya idcliente ya la hayamos introducido en clientes. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: La pregunta no está muy clara, en particular no es del todo claro la clase de datos que hay en tu tabla 2. Sería más útil si incluyeras un ejemplo muy concreto con datos en formato tabular, aunque sea una versión simplificada de tu tabla real, pero que sea concreta y completa. O sea, algo como: *"aquí tengo los datos en las 2 tablas, y el resultado deseado es X..."*

Comment: _Pongamos que un parametro de la tabla 2 es "deportes del cliente", entonces hay un cliente 1 que hace tenis, **y tambien el cliente 1 haciendo futbol**. Pero como yo cojo solo los parametros comunes a la tabla clientes, **meto informacion repetida** y me da error._ Leyéndote, es posible que tu problema sea **de diseño** y se resuelve muy facil: con 3 tablas (clientes, deportes y una 3ª tabla auxiliar donde relacionarías por id los clientes y los deportes que practican). Pero como dice @sstan la pregunta no es del todo clara.

Comment: Ya he agregado lo que me pedíais, a ver si podeis ayudarme ^^  @sstan

Comment: Hola Keka. Está mucho más claro. Antes de publicar una respuesta quiero verificar algunos puntos. 1) ¿La tabla `clientes` está vacía para comenzar? 2) En el caso de registros duplicados de un mismo `idcliente`, ¿pueden haber diferencias/conflictos en los demás campos `nombre`, `apellido1`, etc.., o están garantizados de ser siempre iguales? Si hay diferencias, ¿como determinarías cual de los registros es el que quieres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está resuelto, solo había que minimizar clienteid, y luego un group by clienteid, era yo que ponía mal la sintaxis

Comment: Quizás convendría poner el código final, en caso de que le sirva a futuros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema